# How to reset the Bootstrap Progress bar value to 0 using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here the example of my code below link,

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/SubinVs/Lx82rz75/)

1. Run the progress bar from 0 to 100% using for loop.
2. I want to reset the progress bar to 0%

If I add the below script it does not showing the work of for loop,

```
$('.progress-bar').css('width', '0%').attr('aria-valuenow', 0);
```

Help me to do as sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use to reset progress bar:

```
 $('.progress-bar').css('width', '0%').attr('aria-valuenow', 0);
```

Comment: Hi actually I want to show the proress from 0 to 100% and then reset to 0%. Check this link I already tired https://jsfiddle.net/SubinVs/Lx82rz75/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `setTimeout`

```
setTimeout(function() {
   $('.progress-bar').css('width', '0%').attr('aria-valuenow', 0);
}, 3000);
```

Comment: I tired this already in https://jsfiddle.net/SubinVs/Lx82rz75/ its not working in sequence